# Sending dynamic checkbox values from a VisualForce

Tags: sobject, custom-button, record, map

I created a VisualForce wherein I display values from a map (returned from a custom controller with a SOQL request) using an `apex:repeat`. Each time I display this VisualForce page, the amount of record in the map can vary. Here's the structure of my map:

```
Map<Account, List<SObject>> output = new Map<Account, List<SObject>>();
```

I want to add a checkbox next to every record when I display it on the page, and when I send the form, I want to be able to get the record Ids in a list, like it is possible to do with `{!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType....}` in a custom button formula.

What is the best way to do this from a VisualForce page?

**UPDATE**

If there's no easy way to send a list, I could also do something like :

```
records = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('records').split(',');
```

Every sent records could be appended to a `records` HTTP parameter, and splitted to a list.

**UPDATE 2013/03/01**

I tried the solution provided by @PeterKnole, but it still doesn't seem to populate correctly the `isSelected` boolean.

Here's my VisualForce (just the table):

```
<table class="list" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
    <thead class="rich-table-thead">
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th style="border-right: none" width="20">
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </th>
            <th style="border-left: none">Asset Name</th>
            <th>Serial Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfAssets}" var="Account">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:lightblue" colspan="5">
                    <a href="/{!Account.Id}">{!Account.Name}</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!ListOfAssets[Account]}" var="AssetW">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-right: none">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!AssetW.isSelected}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-left: none">
                        <a href="/{!AssetW.Asset}">{!AssetW.Asset.Name}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {!AssetW.Asset.SerialNumber}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Here's my class:

```
public with sharing class randomNameHere {
    public Map<Account, List<WrapperAsset>> myAssets1   { get;set; }

    public Map<Account, List<WrapperAsset>> getListOfAssets() {
        myAssets1 = new Map<Account, List<WrapperAsset>>();
        List<WrapperAsset> assetWrapper = new List<WrapperAsset>();

        List<Asset> assetList = [
            SELECT
                Name,
                Account.Name,
                Account.Id,
                SerialNumber
            FROM
                Asset
        ];

        for(Asset a : assetList) {
            WrapperAsset aw = new WrapperAsset();
            aw.Asset = a;
            assetWrapper.add(aw);
        }

        for(WrapperAsset a : assetWrapper) {
            List<WrapperAsset> aList = myAssets1.get(a.Asset.Account);
            if(aList == null)
                aList = new List<WrapperAsset>{a};
            else
                aList.add(a);
            myAssets1.put(a.Asset.Account, aList);
        }

        // Returning the map, or null if no Assets
        if(myAssets1.size() > 0)
            return myAssets1;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public PageReference nextButton() {
        List<List<WrapperAsset>> container = myAssets1.values();
        List<WrapperAsset> wa = new List<WrapperAsset>();

        System.debug('Wrapper Assets: ' + container);

        for(List<WrapperAsset> lwa : container)
            for(WrapperAsset waTemp : lwa)
                if(waTemp.isSelected == true)
                    wa.add(waTemp);

        System.debug('Wrapper Assets: ' + wa);

        return null;
    }

    public with sharing class WrapperAsset {
        public Asset    Asset       { get;set; }
        public Boolean  isSelected  { get;set; }

        public WrapperAsset() {
            isSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on my button, the first `System.debug` is returning the Map and the `isSelected` is still at `false`, even if I checked the box.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In most cases the best way to add a checkbox next to items in a list would be a wrapper class around your SObject. When performing some action in your controller, you would then iterate over the list and check to see if each item's checkbox was checked. How are you displaying this list on the page? Are you repeating over `output.values()`, or each list within `output.values()`?

Comment: Here's an [example of Wrapper Class with checkboxes](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class) on developerforce.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKnolle, this link was super useful. Exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to bundle your checkboxes and objects into a wrapper class in Apex, but you can also just use a bit of javascript in your page.

Using an `onClick` event handler for the checboxes, you could iterate over them (use jQuery and a CSS class to find them) and add the values of all selected ones to a string.

```
// psuedocode (i.e. not test, writing in browser)
var theResult = '';

jQuery('.checkBoxes').each(function()
    {
        if(this.attr('checked') !== undefined)
            result += this.attr('value') + ';';
    }
);
```

Then just assign that string to the value of a hidden input field:

```
<!-- Not best practice, but I use unique classes to save the headaches
     involved in jQuery and Salesforce generated IDs -->
<apex:inputHidden value="{!someStringMember}" class="theHiddenField"/>
```

And then you can just split this up in your action method in the controller:

```
someStringMember.split(';');
```